# Python lambda if statement re.sub

Tags: python, regex, replace, lambda

So I am using the following regex to parse text and grab information from a specific dictionary:

```
re.sub(r'(<Q\d+>)',lambda m: quotes[m.group(1)][1],text)
```

What I want to do, is only have it replace if what it would replace with is a key in a separate dictionary. Logically it would look like this:

```
re.sub(r'(<Q\d+>)',lambda m: quotes[m.group(1)][1] if quotes[m.group(1)][1] in d,text)
```

now if I were to run the following, I get the following syntax error:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(<Q\d+>)',lambda m: quotes[m.group(1)][1] if quotes[m.group(1)][1] in d,text)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    re.sub(r'(<Q\d+>)',lambda m: quotes[m.group(1)][1] if quotes[m.group(1)][1] in d,text)
                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**How can I only replace in this way?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `if` expression always requires an `else`.  You always have to replace the matched text.  If you don't want to replace it, you just need to replace it with itself:

```
re.sub(r'(<Q\d+>)', 
  (lambda m: quotes[m.group(1)][1] if quotes[m.group(1)][1] in d else m.group(1)), text)
```

Comment: same syntax error...also why would the else statement go after the comma that seperates the replace statement from the text?

Comment: @RyanSaxe: Sorry, I made a typo and left the `text` in the wrong place, see the updated version.  (You should put spaces after your commas! :-)

Comment: are the parentheses wrapping the lambda necessary?

Comment: @RyanSaxe: The parens are not necessary here, because it's not ambiguous to the parser whether the comma is inside the lambda body or the lambda is a comma-separated argument to `re.sub`. However, if it's not immediately obvious to _you_ that it's not ambiguous, you may want to use them anyway, because code has to be meaningful to human readers, not just to the compiler.